# Magento 2 - Move Product description out of Tab above the add to cart button

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.1, layout-update

How can I move Product description out of Tab, above the add to cart button in magento 2 in luma theme

**Why there is no view.phtml file as in magento 1.x**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Magento 2 many of the .phtml files have been replaced by xml files, if you look in catalog_product_view.xml you will see that this controls the structure of the product page. You can move the description by adding the below to catalog_product_view.xml

```
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.addto"/>
```

I have found the most useful resource is http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

Comment: This seem not to work anymore for Magento 2.1.5. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: This works in 2.1.5

Comment: This doesn't place it above the "Add to Cart" button as OP asked (and nor does changing `after` to `before`).

Comment: Thank you @user7290573, I've updated the code

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, as the description was still below the "Add to Cart" button. I managed to solve my problem with the following:

```
<move element="product.info.description" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
```